# FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING should not strip html from WYSIWYG editor but only unsafe tags like <script>

Tags: php, html, xss

I have written and using following function to remove any unsafe tags to prevent Cross site scripting - XSS::

```
function xss_clean_input($data) {
    if(is_array($data)) {
        $arr_temp = array();
        foreach($data as $key => $val) {
            $temp_val = trim($val);
            $temp_val = filter_var($temp_val, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
            $arr_temp[$key] = $temp_val;
        }
        return $arr_temp;
    }else {
        $data = trim($data);
        return $data = filter_var($data, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    }
}
```

But this function also removes any valid and safe html from WYSIWYG editors for example it strips this

```
<html><body>This is great</body></html>
```

to this

```
This is great
```

Note:: I dont want to use regular expression

Comment: `FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING` says `Strip tags, optionally strip or encode special characters.`

Comment: @Class Correct, but is there any way for the above problem using FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING

Comment: `FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING` simply does not do what you need. Use something else, like http://htmlpurifier.org.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING` at all. It is being removed from PHP and it definitely can't be used for what you want.

There is no such thing as *"unsafe tags"*. XSS comes from not formatting the data properly for the medium in which it is displayed. You can't remove XSS.

I understand though that your requirement is different. You are building HTML from user input. In this case, you require a HTML parser which will be able to whitelist certain HTML tags/features and remove everything else. One such library is [htmlpurifier](http://htmlpurifier.org/)